# Starting service with Alarm Manager on Android?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

Hi a read other question retated to this but the responses never resolve my issue.

I want to start a service after a specific time with an Alarm Manager

```
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmServiceIntent=new Intent(ListActivity.this, AlarmLevelServiceImproved.class);
    alarmServiceIntent.putExtra("username",usernameID);
    alarmServiceIntent.putExtra("password",userPass);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmServiceIntent, 0);

    . . .

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND,10);
    //calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);

    //alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    //        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,alarmIntent);
    //alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    //        1000 * 10, alarmIntent);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
    Log.d("MioLog", "Alarm setted");
```

My service is:

```
public class AlarmLevelServiceImproved extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d("MioLog","MyAlarmService.onCreate()");
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("MioLog","MyAlarmService.onBind()");
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("MioLog","MyAlarmService.onDestroy()");
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("MioLog","MyAlarmService.onStart()");
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}
}
```

And I add this on AndroidManifest.xml (The service class is on the sub-package "services"):

```
 <service
        android:name=".services.AlarmLevelServiceImproved"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

But the service don't start and no log is printed.

Any idea how to start a Service with the AlarmManager?

I also suived [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e5156/start-service-using-alarmmanager-in-android/) but I don't find any difference to my code

Thanks

Comment: Well.. you are not starting your service from anywhere.. You need to start it like `startService(new Intent(this, AlarmLevelServiceImproved .class));`

Comment: Yes I can start the service manually, but i need that service will started every X seconds. How to do this with an AlarmManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a service with a PendingIntent, you need to use the static method `PendingIntent.getService()` to retrieve the appropriate PendingIntent.

Your code seems to be using `PendingIntet.getBroadcast()` for whatever reason. If you intend to have the AlarmManager indeed send a broadcast, you can start your service in your BroadcastReceiver, else change that line to getService():

from

```
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmServiceIntent, 0);
```

to

```
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmServiceIntent, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getBroadcast()` to create the `PendingIntent`, but the `Intent` points to a service. That combination will not work.

Since you are using `RTC_WAKEUP`, you need to use `getBroadcast()` and a `WakeLock` to get reliable results. One approach is to use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` as the base class of your receiver, where you then forward the work onto an `IntentService`.

Also, please do not pass user names and passwords in extras, as those are visible to anything that gets its hands on the `Intent` or `PendingIntent`. In this case, that *should* just be your app and the core OS, but I would still aim to do something a bit more secure.